# node.js lambda function migrate records from sql to elasticsearch, limit async calls using queue

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, elasticsearch, lambda, queue

I'm trying to implement the next function in node.js: I have to migrate 1.200.000 records from sql to elasticsearch, I am separating in batches of 50,000 and once I solved the 5 minutes timeout issue, I'm suffering this out of memory issue in aws lambda. I found this async.queue to limit the asynchronous calls in Node.js but I must be doing something wrong, because it does not work as expected. What am I doing wrong? how can I limit asynchronous calls to the importSQLData method?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
exports.importData = function (batchNum, topNum, startNum) {

var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
    console.log('hello ' + task.name);
    callback();
}, 2);

q.drain = function () {
    console.log('all items have been processed');
}

for (var y = 1; y <= batchNum; y++) {
    q.push(importSQLData(topNum, startNum), callback); // I don't know if this is ok
    if (y > 1) startNum = startNum + topNum;

    importSQLData(topNum, startNum)
        .then(function (importRes) {
            //console.log(importRes);
            console.log("Import successful! Execution Time Time(ms): " + importRes.took);
            console.log("memory usage:", process.memoryUsage());
            //callback(null, "done");
        }).catch(function (importErr) {
            let error = {
                StatusCode: importErr.status,
                Response: importErr.response,
                Message: importErr.message
            };
            let errorMsg = new Error(error.Message);
            //context.fail(errorMsg);
            callback(errorMsg);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I read the async documentation but I'm not seeing how to implement it here.